# Showing $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+k}$ is not an integer.

Tags: number-theory

> Show that if $n, k \in \mathbb{Z}, n>1, k>0$, then
>   $$\frac{1}{n} +  \frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n+k}$$
>   is not an integer.

I thought about showing the result by first showing $k \geq n$ and using the fact that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a prime $p$ such that $n <p \leq 2n$, but am not sure if there is another way. If not, how can we proceed and conclude?

EDIT: There is a question like this already asked that I did not see. I do not need assistance with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(i)$ be the greatest $j\ge 0$ such that $2^j$ divides $i$. Now, there will be always *exactly* one maximum in the set 
$$
\left\{f(n),f(n+1),\ldots,f(n+k)\right\}.
$$
Hence $\sum_{i\le k}\frac{1}{n+i}$ cannot be an integer.